# Did Anakin share his Qui-Gon experience in Attack Of The Clones?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

After the Tusken Raiders torture and cause the death of his mother, Anakin Skywalker conducts a one-man massacre of the sand people, just when he was about to start, we hear Quin-Gon Jinn's voice (taken from Episode I during Maul's Attack) saying **Anakin, Anakin** *Nooo* (The no is controversial if it was said by Anakin or Qui-Gon), then the scene cuts to Yoda meditating and sensing *young Skywalker's terrible pain*.

According to many sources Qui-Gon hasn't learned yet a way to become the Force-ghost so we only get to hear his voice, so did Anakin hear him? if so why hadn't he shared that with Padmé when he was *confessing* later or even with Ob-Wan and/or Yoda? or did he do that is some Canon or Legends material?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/why-couldnt-qui-gon-jinns-force-ghost-warn-yoda-when-anakin-killed-the-tusken , https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128773/was-qui-gon-guiding-anakin , https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11188/did-qui-gons-force-ghost-try-to-contact-darth-vader-over-the-years ,...

Comment: Very helpful, but I was asking if he **shared** that encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During his life time, [Qui-Gon Jinn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn) *did* learn about how to manifest his consciousness after death.

> **Sometime during his life, Jinn began discovering the secrets to
> manifesting his consciousness after death.** He traveled to a planet
> strong with the Force, a world that legend said was the birthplace of
> life and the origin of midi-chlorians. He learned from five Force
> Priestesses who had retained their consciousness after death. He
> learned that, when a living thing died, its life passed through the
> Living Force and into the Cosmic Force to become one with the Force.
> As the Living Force and Cosmic Force existed in tandem, it became
> possible for one to retain consciousness and physically manifest
> themselves after death. Jinn was considered worthy of the knowledge of
> eternal life and secretly began his training to unlock its mysteries
> fully. He also learned from a Shaman of the Whills that achieving
> eternal consciousness required absolute selflessness.

But as you mention, his training was incomplete, so he could only manifest his voice through the Force...

> Though his training had been incomplete, Jinn utilized what he learned
> from the Force Priestesses **to become one with the Force and retain his
> identity after his death. However, he hadn't fully learned the
> mystery, so he could not physically manifest himself, only speak as a
> disembodied voice.** The first known time that Jinn communicated
> through the Force was approximately ten years after the events on
> Naboo. Skywalker had returned to Tatooine to find his mother, about
> whom he had been having recurring nightmares, and discovered she had
> been kidnapped by Tusken Raiders. He found her in a Tusken camp, but
> she died only moments later. In his anger, Skywalker slaughtered all
> the Tuskens in the camp. Feeling the great pain and distress, Jinn
> called out to Skywalker through the Force, which Yoda could hear—but
> not comprehend—through his own meditations. However, Jinn's pleas were
> for naught, as Skywalker didn't heed his words in his uncontrolled
> rage.

Obi-Wan Kenobi also later had "visions" of Qui-Gon (*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*), and the reason for this was due to the planet Obi-Wan was located on, which due to Geological Force properties, enhanced the potential for connection. Qui-Gon also was seen by Ahsoka Tano, and eventually Yoda by Yoda learning as well how to connect with Qui-Gon (which you have also already mentioned).

As for your question about 'IF' Anakin ever shared his experience?

No. There *currently* is no canonical source that reveals this. As far as we know, he did not and seemingly, no one ever questioned him about it.

Comment: It should be noted though that voices, whether current or from the past, can also be heard via the World Between Worlds as well. Rey hears many voices of Jedi/Light Side Force Users via this method when confronting Darth Sidious towards the end of The Rise of Skywalker.

Comment: The Clone Wars also seems to contradict the movies, Obi-Wan was surprised when Yoda told him about it in ROTS ending despite talking to him during the wars, there is still a debate whether Liam Neeson did film something but in an deleted scene (not yet seen it), I heard that he did communicate with Yoda only through voice.

Comment: I was talking about Yoda and Obi-Wan in Revenge Of The Sith.

Comment: Yes, I am too. Qui-gon never fully retains his ability to manifest a physical form, but he is able to reach Yoda and manifest in new ways, leading Yoda through a series of trials (so Yoda can learn how to be become a full force spirit after death) during 3 episodes of The Clone Wars, which takes place BEFORE ROTS. So when Yoda says that to Obi-Wan in ROTS, he is teaching Obi-Wan how to both commune with Qui-Gon and to start his training become a full Force spirit too. Obi-Wan does then talk with Qui-Gon's spirit (just not in physical form) after ROTS, while he is looking aftr Luke on Tatooine.